# Why does this return 1 number and then stops the loop? PHP

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I'm a beginner at PHP, so my code might not be efficient or good.
Why does this code return 1 number and then stops the loop? It's supposed to stop the loop when "the dice" rolled two of every number (1,2,3,4,5,6). But now it stops after randomly generating 1 number..

```
   <?php
        $sixCount = 0;
        $fiveCount = 0;
        $fourCount = 0;
        $threeCount = 0;
        $twoCount = 0;
        $oneCount = 0;
        $rollCount = 0;
        do{
            $roll = rand(1,6);
            $rollCount++;
            if($roll == 6){
                $sixCount++;
                echo "6";
            } else if($roll == 5){
                $fiveCount++;
                echo "5";
            } else if($roll == 4){
                $fourCount++;
                echo "4";
            } else if($roll == 3){
                $threeCount++;
                echo "3";
            } else if($roll == 2){
                $twoCount++;
                echo "2";
            } else {
                $oneCount++;
                echo "1";
            }
        } while($sixCount < 3 && $sixCount > 1 && $fiveCount < 3 && $fiveCount > 1 && $fourCount < 3 && $fourCount > 1 && $threeCount < 3 && $threeCount > 1 && $twoCount < 3 && $twoCount > 1 && $oneCount < 3 && $oneCount > 1);
        echo "<br />It took {$rollCount} rolls!";
    ?>
```

This is an exercise from Codecademy.com!

Thanks,
Jesper (New at Stackoverflow!)

Comment: Wouldn't a switch statement make sense here?

Comment: There are good answers and explanation as to why it doesn't work, and answers as to the rethink you need. You need to carefully think about each criteria of your conditions. And when you have a lot of `&&`, the potential for them all to be true is very limited. You conditions specifically state all vars need to be > 1, however you start with all vars = 0, and only roll the dice once.. (I wont put as an answer, as there are already more than enough..)

Answer (score 2):

After first execution of loop, you cannot have `$sixCount > 1 && $fiveCount > 1`, among other conditions.

Answer (score 1):

After first roll, suppose it's 3, your variables are:

```
    $sixCount = 0;
    $fiveCount = 0;
    $fourCount = 0;
    $threeCount = 1;
    $twoCount = 0;
    $oneCount = 0;
```

It doesn't suit while conditions, cuz, for example, `$sixCount > 1` is false and other vars too.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` expression says:

```
while ($sixCount < 3 && $sixCount > 1 && $fiveCount < 3 && $fiveCount > 1 ...
```

If $sixCount is less than 3 and more than 1 that implies $sixCount equals 2. Ditto for the others. So it means "keep looping while $sixCount equals 2 **and** $fiveCount equals 2 **and** [all the others equal 2]".

You start with those variables at 0:

```
$sixCount = 0;
$fiveCount = 0;
...
```

So the loop condition is not initially met. The loop allows *at most one* of them to be incremented *at most once*:

```
$roll = rand(1, 6);
if ($roll == 6) {
    $sixCount++;
    echo "6";
} else if ($roll == 5) {
    $fiveCount++;
    echo "5";
} ...
```

No matter what number is rolled it is impossible to get *any* of the counts to 2 by the end of a single roll, and certainly not *all* of them, so the loop condition will not be met, and the loop will inevitably stop.

> It's supposed to stop the loop when "the dice" rolled two of every number (1,2,3,4,5,6)

In that case, the correct condition would be:

```
while ($sixCount < 2 && $fiveCount < 2 && ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your conditional for the while loop will never be true. Instead, you want to make sure the variables aren't all at 2. Try this instead:

```
while ($sixCount < 2 || $fiveCount < 2 || $fourCount < 2 || $threeCount < 2 || $twoCount < 2 || $oneCount < 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just adapted your script. It can be a funny game.
It rolls 6 dice times 2 (6 x 2) and then if requirements are not met, it rolls the dice again :

```
$rollCount = 0;
do{
    $sixCount = 0;
    $fiveCount = 0;
    $fourCount = 0;
    $threeCount = 0;
    $twoCount = 0;
    $oneCount = 0;
    $rollCount++;
    for ($i= 0; $i< 2 * 6; $i++) {
        $roll = rand(1,6);
        if($roll == 6){
            $sixCount++;
            echo "6";
        } else if($roll == 5){
            $fiveCount++;
            echo "5";
        } else if($roll == 4){
            $fourCount++;
            echo "4";
        } else if($roll == 3){
            $threeCount++;
            echo "3";
        } else if($roll == 2){
            $twoCount++;
            echo "2";
        } else {
            $oneCount++;
            echo "1";
        }
    }
    echo "_";
} while(!($sixCount < 3 && $sixCount > 1 && $fiveCount < 3 && $fiveCount > 1 && $fourCount < 3 && $fourCount > 1 && $threeCount < 3 && $threeCount > 1 && $twoCount < 3 && $twoCount > 1 && $oneCount < 3 && $oneCount > 1));
    echo "<br />It took {$rollCount} rolls!";
    $a = array(
    $sixCount,
    $fiveCount,
    $fourCount,
    $threeCount,
    $twoCount,
    $oneCount);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($a);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Giving this king of output :

```
262225451666_535451252543_666153663214_652652635413_522615315213_412123422526_113553235335_255616351453_124215216465_112544353243_161145351612_522462262355_114331531645_563664155335_455623424146_233336226515_213136514365_646344361534_445325236533_423153546564_324466143565_422464136444_631511342612_516266141216_613556242333_351541131651_554665566244_261433652145_
It took 28 rolls!
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 2
)
```